# Magento disable backup

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

Is there any way to disable the Magento Backup ?

When going to:

**Admin Panel** -> **System** -> **Tools** -> **Backups**

I can see a lot of Backups which are creating daily. I just want to have a option to change this to (maybe): *Backup every 1 week* or to *do not backup*.

Is tehre any way to do this ? I did not find anything in the configuration menu and also tried to google the problem.

The version I am using is: **1.6.2.0**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about 1.6 but the settings in 1.9 can be found under 
`System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Scheduled Backup Settings`